# Angular 2. Как обработать HTTP запрос в сервисе, и передать observable ниже по цепочке?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Есть следующая структура проекта

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не понимаю, как получить ошибку в сервисе UserService, обработать в ErrorService, и получить результат в компоненте.

А если нет ошибки то отправить observable в компонент, чтобы подписаться там на него и получить данные. Или даже отправлять в компонент сразу данные, но как тогда сделать это асинхронно?

MyHttpService.ts

```
export class MyHttpService {
   constructor(private http: Http) {}

   getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(url);
   }
}
```

UserService.ts

```
 export class UserService{
      constructor(private http: MyHttpService) {}

      getUsers(){
        return this.http.getData('http://getUsers.com');
      }
 }
```

Comment: Мне кажется может помочь метод `switchMap`. Что-нибудь типа `return this.http.getData('http://getUsers.com').switchMap((response) => response.status === 'OK' ? Observable.of(response) : this.errorService.getErrorMessageObservable(response));`

Comment: Как насчёт использования EventEmmiter ? В юзер сервис создайте евент имитеры для ошибки и успешного запроса. Потом выполняйте emit  в методе  getUser в зависимости от результата запроса. А в компоненте и ерорсервисе подпишитесь на эмиттеры